# Reverse proxy smtp (EXIM)

Tags: proxy, exim

I wonder if there is any possibility to receive and set original ip address in exim ? I have an NGINX proxy where I used "proxy_pass" and "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For" in order to get the REAL ip address within apache runtime, there is any posibility to do it aswell for exim ?

I need the "client" real ip address in order to check for spamlists, spf records and so on, I know that I could install exim on the proxy server and configure it with everything needed to do these checks and relay to master exim server but configuration often changes and it would be easier to maintain everything from one place.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Doing [SRS](http://www.openspf.org/SRS) in exim will allow you to do the header rewrites.